# why does "aabbcc"[/ab*/] only return "a"?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-2.3

If the quantifier `*` represents, 'zero or more times,' it seems like `"aabbcc"[/ab*/]` should return `"abb"` but it returns only `"a"`.

Comment: Why? `'a'` contains `b` zero or more times, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

The regex returns exactly what you asked : the first occurence of 1 `a` followed by 0 or more `b`.

If you want all the non-overlapping occurences, you could use [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan) :

```
"aabbcc".scan(/ab*/)
#=> ["a", "abb"]
```

If you want to have a least 1 `b`, you could use `b+` :

```
"aabbcc"[/ab+/]
#=> "abb"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I just learned it's because the left-most match wins and since there's a single `a` that matches before the `abb` that's what's returned.

Comment: A very good resource for testing ruby regexp is http://rubular.com/. As you already noted regex return the first match and ab* matches `a` as well as `abb`. Also note that regex is also greedy by default so /a*c/ will match `aabbcc` (annoying when matching braces as you sometimes end up with matching the last brace in your string not the one that actually closes a brace.

Comment: @Tigraine: For that, you'd need `/\(.*?\)/` or `/\([^\)]*\)/`

Comment: @Tigraine: `"aabbcc"[/a*c/]` returns `c`

Comment: ah sorry i meant `/a.*c/` :) it will match both c not only to the first one.

Comment: Please don't use answers for commenting.